# FullCalendar - set allDay: false color

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is there a way to set the text color of an allDay: false type of event? I'd like to be able to change it since that Basic blue its pretty bad in My calendar

Comment: [Documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventColor) is made for cases like yours.

Comment: I don't think that that documentato can help to change the textcolor of a non allday event.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `eventClassNames` - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/classname-input

for example:

```
eventClassNames: function(arg) {
  if (arg.event.allDay) {
    return [ 'all-day' ]
  } else {
    return [ 'not-all-day' ]
  }
}
```

Then have two CSS classes, and alter the style as you wish

```
.fc-event.all-day {color: white; background-color: red; }
.fc-event.not-all-day {color: yellow; background-color: green; }
```